# Spring MVC with ajax file upload and MultipartFile

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue using Ajax upload with Spring 3 MVC. I understand that I have to configure multipartResolver bean in spring config, which I've done. Than I can have controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/settingsSim")
@ResponseBody
public Map uploadSimSettings(@RequestParam(value="qqfile", required=true) MultipartFile settings) {
 Map<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 return ret;
}
```

The problem is that when I actually send the request to the server (actually valums Ajax file upload does this for me), I get an Internal server error response and nothing is shown in the logs. I am really scratching my head now, as I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Stack trace would be helpful to diagnose

Comment: Yes it would, and that is the main reason I am asking here, because there is no stack trace from the container whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [valums](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) plugin I solved this problem by using `@RequestBody` Spring annotation.
You could rewrite your code as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/settingsSim",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map uploadSimSettings(@RequestBody String body) {
 /*
 some controller logic 
 */
}
```

Note that the variable `body` will contain the contents of the uploaded file. Also there is no method declaration in your example which means that your method will be mapped to GET request.

P.S. I also had this "no multipart boundary" problem when parsing request with Apache Commons. `HttpServletRequest#getParts()` returns just an empty collection.

Answer (score 3):

my solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="multipart/form-data", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody()
public String handleImageUpload(@RequestParam(value="qqfile", required=true) MultipartFile[] files, 
        @ModelAttribute(value="files") List<MultipartFile> filesSession) throws IOException, FileUploadException {

    if (files.length > 0) {
        filesSession.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));
        // store the bytes somewhere
        return  "{\"success\": true}";
    }
    else {
        return "{\"success\": false}";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/octet-stream", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody()
public String handleImageUploadApplication(HttpServletRequest request, 
        @ModelAttribute(value="files") List<MultipartFile> filesSession) throws IOException, FileUploadException {

    if (request.getInputStream() != null) {
        // creamos el fichero temporal
        File file = File.createTempFile("file", "valumns",
                RepositoryData.getRepositoryData());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // copiamos contenido
        Streams.copy(request.getInputStream(), fos, true);
        //TODO: 
        //filesSession.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));
        // store the bytes somewhere
        return  "{\"success\": true}";
    }
    else {
        return  "{\"success\": true}";
    }
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
public void handleException(Exception ex) {
    log.error("Ocurrio un error en el album", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the fineuploader (valums), and I tried using request.getInputStream() but did not get it to work.

The @ResponseBody annotation worked but I got the whole body with headers. I thought processing that and stripping off the unwanted chunks was not very elegant. 
I looked further and found the solution is this post:

[problem with spring ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430356/problem-with-spring-ajax-file-upload)

Like it is said, I added the bean configuration for the multipart resolver to my spring configuration

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

After that, I could easily retrieve my file using

```
 public @ResponseBody Map ajaxUploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile qqfile) { ... }
```

Don't forget to add the Apache **commons-io.jar** and **commons-fileupload.jar** libraries in your project to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

@Tomas I encountered same issue while using the same jquery plugin. Please change the Content-Type in the plugin code to xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); on my plugin its line 1203, after this its now showing a stack trace, however I am encountering another issue where the logs are printing :
Sep 8, 2011 9:43:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Answer (score 1):

As per my observation the file upload plugin does not send a multipart file but sends a stream. I could get it to work by declaring the controller method to accept filename as request param qqfile and the second parameter as httprequest. I then did further processing using request.getinputstream. Hope that helps!

Regards,

Pradyumna