# How to upload a file using the PUT method via Ajax in Spring MVC?

Tags: ajax, spring, file-upload, put, apache-commons-fileupload

I have the following js code to send an Ajax request to a URL which maps a method in Spring MVC.

```
function update(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        datatype:"json",
        type: "put",
        url: "/wagafashion/ajax/TempAjax.htm",
        data: "id=" + id+"&t="+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);                        
        },
        error: function(e)
        {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

and the following is the simple Spring form that has only a file browser and a button.

```
<form:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="post" action="Temp.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" commandName="tempBean">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" onclick="update(1);" value="Submit"/>
    <!--The js function is called when this button is clicked supplying 1 as id.-->
</form:form>
```

The following method in Spring controller is invoked when that button is pressed.

```
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.PUT}, value={"ajax/TempAjax"})
public @ResponseBody String update(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    System.out.println(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request));
    return "Message";
}
```

The method call `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)` however returns `false`.

---

When I modify the method as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.PUT}, value={"ajax/TempAjax"}, headers={"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    System.out.println(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request));
    return "Message";
}
```

the error section in the js code always alerts `Error: [object Object]`. The same thing happens even if the `POST` method is used, in this case.

How to pass multipart contents via Ajax (precisely using the `PUT` method)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see how this is meant to post the multipart file to the server? The data just contains the id and a time.

Try something like:

```
function update(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        datatype:"json",
        type: "put",
        url: "/wagafashion/ajax/TempAjax.htm",
        data: $('#mainForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);                        
        },
        error: function(e)
        {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The alert box in the error section only says, "*Error: [object Object]*" even with `data: $('#mainForm').serialize(),`, no luck.

Comment: Have you defined a multipart resolver in your spring context? As described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405415/302387

Comment: Yes I have defined that `MultipartResolver` in my `applicationContext.xml` file and it works fine (without Ajax) but JavaScript always says, "*Error: [object Object]*", in case of Ajax.

Comment: From the jQuery docs: typeString
Default: 'GET'
The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: I also tried to change the request method to POST but it doesn't appear to upload a file using AJAX without using some techniques like  a hidden iframe. There are some [jquery plugins](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/) that address it in different ways. [Also](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader).