# upload multiple files with html5 multiple attribute - spring mvc

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload multiple files using html5 attribute multiple. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924809/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-with-html5-multiple-file-form-feature) provide me a good start. However, I am facing a problem that I am not be able to read multipartFile in my controller.

Here is my POjO class

```
public class FileProduct {

    private String name;
    private List<MultipartFile> images;

}
```

My Controller

```
public String processNewListing(Model model
                            , @ModelAttribute FileProduct product
                            , HttpServletRequest request
            ) {
        List<MultipartFile> files = product.getImages();
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        log.info("Files legnth: " + files.size());
        log.info("name: " + product.getName());
}
```

And this if my form:

```
 <form:form commandName="product" action="${newListingForm }" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <form:input path="name" type="text"/>
     <form:input path="images" type="file" multiple=""/>
     <input type="submit">

 </form:form>
```

So I am able to print out the "name" in my controller but my "files" is always has size of 1 regardless I have selected any file or not. I have followed the suggestion in the link to include common-fileupload and common-io, but the problem is not fix.

Comment: try `multiple=""` change to `multiple`

Comment: I have tried to change it to multiple or multiple="multiple" but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

in jsp use following

```
<form ation="your/path" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

in controller use following

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest;

public String yourMethod(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){

}
```

this should resolve your problem